# Highlighting a qtreewidget column on hover

Tags: c++, qt

I have a QTreeWidget where the row is highlighted on mouse over using a qwidget item stylesheet. I was wanting the column to be highlighted too so that it is really obvious to the user which row and column they are selecting.

Anyone have any ideas of the best way of going about that? Preferably using stylesheets, but programatically is fine too.

Comment: You can track mouse events and keep `QModelIndex` of hovered item. Then, in your custom delegate, you may draw highlighting for whole column.

Comment: It's the drawing of the whole column that I'm struggling with.